# How to authenticate with an Ethereum account through personalSign?

Tags: metamask, signature, web3-providers, authentication

I want to authenticate a user using her Ethereum account. There are several demos and tutorials available, for example [Amaury's](https://www.toptal.com/ethereum/one-click-login-flows-a-metamask-tutorial) which uses, however, the [deprecated web3](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/provider-migration.html#replacing-window-web3) API:

```js
web3.personal.sign(web3.fromUtf8("Hello from Toptal!"), web3.eth.coinbase, console.log);
```

> `MetaMask no longer injects web3. For details, see: https://docs.metamask.io/guide/provider-migration.html#replacing-window-web3`
>
> `Uncaught TypeError: web3.personal is undefined`

I'm using the new `window.ethereum` directly, which works well to connect to a wallet provider and retrieve accounts, e.g.:

```js
const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
```

However, it does not really expose `eth_personalSign` as [suggested in the MetaMask docs](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/accessing-accounts.html):

> - `eth_sendTransaction`
> - `eth_sign` (insecure and unadvised to use)
> - `eth_personalSign`
> - `eth_signTypedData`

```js
const sig = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_personalSign', params: ['0x0', 'foo'] });
```

> MetaMask - RPC Error: The method 'eth_personalSign' does not exist / is not available.

How to authenticate with an Ethereum account through `personalSign`?

I experimented with `eth_sign` instead, which at least goes through to the web3 provider and allows me to sign a message in MetaMask. But it is cumbersome to handle and does only return a forever *pending* promise...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's `personal_sign` now, not `eth_personalSign`. It has always been `personal_sign`, it's probably just a typo in the Metamask docs.

```js
const message = "Hello from Ethereum Stack Exchange!";
const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
const account = accounts[0];
const signature = await ethereum.request({ method: 'personal_sign', params: [ message, account ] });
```

Comment: nope, I'm getting an error that is it not supported...